# What is the difference between Javascript and ECMA script?

Tags: javascript

What would happen if I start to define my script tags as ECMA?  Will it execute to a different standard?

Does anyone actually use ECMA script instead of straight up Javascript...?

Comment: Not sure if it is a duplicate, but this was asked earlier today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269150/what-is-ecmascript Here's a question with almost the exact same title: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912479/what-is-the-difference-between-javascript-and-ecmascript

Comment: Asked and answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912479/what-is-the-difference-between-javascript-and-ecmascript

Comment: Here I found a good link that explain the difference between JavaScript and ECMAScript:    https://medium.freecodecamp.org/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-ecmascript-cba48c73a2b5

Answer (score 29, accepted):

ECMAScript is a standard. JavaScript is an implementation of that standard (edition 3 of that standard to be more exact).

Other implementations of ECMAScript are ActionScript and JScript.

Also note that there isn't *one JavaScript*. Each JavaScript engine may implement its own version of the language as long as it meets the ECMAScript requirements. This means that browsers (JS engines) **may** have additional functionality, but they all **must** have the base ECMAScript functionality.

And now, to answer your question, according to [RFC 4329](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4329.txt), if the media type is set to `application/ecmascript`, rather than `application/javascript`, it must adhere to a stricter standard.

> This document defines equivalent
>   processing requirements for the types
>   text/javascript, text/ecmascript, and
>   application/javascript. Use of and
>   support for the media type
>   application/ecmascript is considerably
>   less widespread than for other media
>   types defined in this document.  Using
>   that to its advantage, this document
>   defines stricter processing rules for
>   this type to foster more interoperable
>   processing.

Comment: Don't use `application/*` as script type, IE will choke on that.

Comment: Good point, but I wanted to use `application/*`, rather than `text/*`, to conform to the RFC recommendations. The arguments still apply if you replace with `text/*`.

Comment: I'm not following exactly. Is it sort of like saying that by standard you mean  syntax and common set of features ( like an interface in java ) , and maybe one implementation could allow additional things like say, lambdas whereas another implementation may not ?

Comment: @AbhinavVishak What you stated is correct. You can look at it this way... ES:JS ~ Interface:Implementation. Or at least this is how it should be, ideally. In practice though, things are a bit more complicated and there are a lot of articles available online for those who want to understand more. As a note, here are a couple of ways in which ES differs from an Interface. For one, nobody is enforcing that an ES implementation actually respects the standard. And second ES, at least in its most recent incarnation has become a living standard. It's modular and has quick iterations.

Comment: Here I found a good link that explain the difference between JavaScript and ECMAScript:    https://medium.freecodecamp.org/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-ecmascript-cba48c73a2b5

Answer (score 3):

ECMAScript is a programming language standard, like lisp. Javascript is an implementation of such, along with non-ECMAScript features like the DOM. ActionScript(for Flash) is another one. Just like writing in "lisp" means writing in some dialect like Common Lisp or Scheme, actually writing straight-up ECMAScript might not only be pointless, but unusable in the dialects(although I think ActionScript 3 and recent JavaScript apply the whole ECMAScript standard).