# what is global properties means in javascript

Tags: javascript

Today I'm reading "javascript the definitive guide." in chapter 3.5 talk about the global object.There said:

> global properties like undefined, infinity, and NaN

Because of my lack knowledge, I feel I could not understand it.
In my mind, I feel undefined Infinity and NaN are values
I don't know how could these are properties.
Thanks for any thoughts.

wow javascript is so confusing I just check this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined

undefined is a property and this property value is also undefined.

if this understanding is wrong please correct me.

Comment: They are both values and properties of the `window` object (for example). Additionally, `undefined` is a type.

Comment: @Xufox ok I see thank you so much. by the way the window object is belongs to BOM?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The Global properties refers the variables that can be used anywhere throughout the document and need not be declared.

I would provide you this [**standard ECMA Language Specification**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) for complete reference.

---

1. **Update: For Down voters.**

> The reason to provide ECMA as a reference is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271676/what-is-the-difference-between-javascript-and-ecma-script)

---

2. Update: **undefined is a property and this property value is also
   undefined.**

> Your understanding this perfectly correct.

---

Explanation is as:

- undefined value

  ```
       primitive value used when a variable has not been assigned a value
  ```
- Undefined type

  ```
       type whose sole value is the undefined value
  ```

as mentioned in the above standard link in sections **4.3.9** and **4.3.10**.
I was trying to convey this message but I posted just the link.

Comment: This is not an answer, it’s just a link.

Answer (score 0):

It simply means that they could be used in anywhere of your code at any time, i.e, they are always available to you in any scope of code.

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_global.asp

Comment: @user3658992 Do not post “thanks” comments. Instead upvote helpful answers and accept the most helpful one.

Answer (score 0):

Properties of the global object are properties you can use anywhere without specifying the object

- Instead of `window.undefined` you can write `undefined`
- Instead of `window.console.log` you can write `console.log`
- etc...