# type="text/ecmascript" vs type="text/javascript"

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I was reading a book about learning JavaScript, and there was these paragraphs:

> ...in middle of 1997, Microsoft  and Netscape, with associate of 
>   European Computer Manufactures Association,
>  released the first
>   version of a standard that named `ECMAScript` or with official form
>   `ECMA-262`...

As much as I was found in this book and something like this, JavaScript and ECMAScript are the same and are different just in name.

From other hand, in Dreamweaver, bracket, and some other editors, there's some autocomplete suggestion like this:

[image]

when I want to add a script tag to my page.

I want to know if there are differences between `ECMAScript` and `Javascript` and when should I use `text/javascript` or `text/ecmascript`?

Comment: you don't need either anymore...

Comment: `Javascript` is what everyone else calls it, `EMCAscript` is the official ISO-backed specification, because the JS standard is under the stewardship of ECMA.

Comment: Voting to reopen, as the questions linked as duplicates of this one don't specifically address when to use the `text/ecmascript` MIME type.

Comment: I checked links in top of the question and as the @legosica said; there is no direct reference to the fact... how can I vote for reopen?

Comment: I think you can't because of your reputation...

Comment: Found some details here which could be useful for someone.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4271687/2860358

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between javascript and ecma script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271676/what-is-the-difference-between-javascript-and-ecma-script)

Comment: It would be much better if it was called ECMAscript to avoid confusion with Java

Answer (score 24, accepted):

*TL;DR Just omit the `type` tag, if you don't care about old browsers.*

ECMAScript is a language specification standardized by ECMA International as [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html) and [ISO/IEC 16262](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=55755). JavaScript is a programming language that implements this specification. ECMAScript exists in several editions. The latest edition is the 6th (in 2016), but most JavaScript implementations are only 5th edition compliant so far.

Besides ECMAScript common JavaScript implementations usually add more functionality, which might be standardized by other institutions (like the W3C) or might be proprietary (aka "browser-specific") features of the specific implementation. So you could say, that ECMAScript represents a subset of JavaScript.

However, the MIME types for JavaScript code are defined in the [RFC 4329](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4329.txt) document, which states that `text/javascript` and `text/ecmascript` are both obsolete and should be replaced by `application/javascript` and `application/ecmascript`:

> Use of the "text" top-level type for this kind of content is known to
>   be problematic.  This document thus defines text/javascript and text/
>   ecmascript but marks them as "obsolete".

The RFC defines stricter processing rules for the `application/ecmascript` than for `application/javascript`, but this refers to the handling of MIME-type parameters and the character encoding and not to the interpretation of the code itself:

> In the cited case, implementations of the types text/javascript, text/ecmascript, and application/javascript SHOULD and implementations of the type application/ecmascript MUST implement the requirements defined in this section: [...]
>
> For the application/ecmascript media type, implementations MUST NOT process content labeled with a "version" parameter as if no such parameter had been specified; [...]
>
> The following error processing behavior is RECOMMENDED for the media types text/javascript, text/ecmascript, and application/javascript, and REQUIRED for the media type application/ecmascript.

Apart from the RFCs, there is also the HTML5-Standard by the W3C: [Older versions](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/the-script-element.html#the-script-element) of it say, that the default value for an empty `type` attribute is `application/javascript`, but [newer versions](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-script-element) don't mention any specific MIME-type anymore. Instead they define any `script` tag with no type or a MIME-type as a so-called "classic script":

> Omitting the attribute, setting it to the empty string, or setting it to a JavaScript MIME type essence match, means that the script is a classic script, to be interpreted according to the JavaScript Script top-level production. Classic scripts are affected by the async and defer attributes, but only when the src attribute is set. Authors should omit the type attribute instead of redundantly setting it.

In general I would omit the `type` attribute (as recommended by the HTML5-Standard) or use `type="text/javascript"`, if you have to support older browsers. A HTTP-Server should serve JavaScript code as `application/javascript`.

Comment: I've never seen this `application/javascript` or `application/ecmascript` in the intellisense while providing `type` attribute of `script` tag. I work on asp.net and asp.net mvc applications using Visual Studio.

Comment: @RBT Even though your code completion does not suggest these types, they are valid. However, with HTML5 you don't need the type-attribute at all.

Comment: ohh. Thanks for the info. I saw it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4195504/465053) that `type` attribute has a default value `text/javascript` starting HTML5 so it has become optional. Nice. Less typing :). I hope some time down the line the default will become `application/javascript` in next version of HTML as per the RFC you've cited.

Comment: For web-applications, we should most likely stick to `text/javascript`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types#textjavascript

Comment: [@Malvoz](/users/9314312/malvoz) Thanks for the hint, I've updated my answer.

Comment: when i first became aware of the diff javascript mime types, i thought the `application` one would have been reserved for and indicative of electron applications and the like. guess i was wrong

Answer (score 1):

The [current version of the HTML standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-script-element) (**last updated 16 July 2019**) says that the language type specified with the `type` attribute of the `<script>` tag falls back to `text/javascript` if ommitted.

Also that specification [specifies](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#scriptingLanguages) that:

> Servers should use text/javascript for JavaScript resources. Servers should not use other [JavaScript MIME types](https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/#javascript-mime-type) for JavaScript resources, and must not use non-[JavaScript MIME types](https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/#javascript-mime-type).