# Multiple search filter in a list javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

[W3School's Example](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp) gives the example of search filter on a list. 
I am wondering how can I do the search filter on more than 1 data in a list. 
For example, I want to search not only names, but also ages and then places. The order is based on which one user enter first.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    dd = li[i].getElementsByTagName("dd")[0];
    if (dd.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>My Friends</h2>

<input type="text" id="myName" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
<input type="text" id="myAge" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for ages.." title="Type in a name">
<input type="text" id="myPlace" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for place.." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><dt>Name</dt>
    <dd href="#">Adele</dd><dt>Age</dt>
    <dd>16</dd><dt>Place</dt>
    <dd>New York</dd>
  </li>
  <li><dt>Name</dt>
    <dd href="#">Mary</dd><dt>Age</dt>
    <dd>17</dd><dt>Place</dt>
    <dd>New Jersey</dd>
  </li>
  <li><dt>Name</dt>
    <dd href="#">Belle</dd><dt>Age</dt>
    <dd>19</dd><dt>Place</dt>
    <dd>New Mexico</dd>
  </li>
  <li><dt>Name</dt>
    <dd href="#">Adele</dd><dt>Age</dt>
    <dd>16</dd><dt>Place</dt>
    <dd>Pennsylvania</dd>
  </li>
  <li><dt>Name</dt>
    <dd href="#">Adele</dd><dt>Age</dt>
    <dd>18</dd><dt>Place</dt>
    <dd>New York</dd>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this function:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var i, dd,
      name = document.getElementById("myName").value.toUpperCase(),
      age = document.getElementById("myAge").value.toUpperCase(),
      place = document.getElementById("myPlace").value.toUpperCase(),
      ul = document.getElementById("myUL"),
      li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    dd = Array.from(li[i].getElementsByTagName("dd"), 
            dd => dd.textContent.toUpperCase());
    li[i].style.display = 
        (dd[0].indexOf(name) | dd[1].indexOf(age) | dd[2].indexOf(place)) >= 0
            ? "" : "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myName" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
<input type="text" id="myAge" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for ages.." title="Type in a name">
<input type="text" id="myPlace" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for place.." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><dt>Name</dt><dd href="#">Adele</dd><dt>Age</dt><dd>16</dd><dt>Place</dt><dd>New York</dd></li>
  <li><dt>Name</dt><dd href="#">Mary</dd><dt>Age</dt><dd>17</dd><dt>Place</dt><dd>New Jersey</dd></li>
  <li><dt>Name</dt><dd href="#">Belle</dd><dt>Age</dt><dd>19</dd><dt>Place</dt><dd>New Mexico</dd></li>
  <li><dt>Name</dt><dd href="#">Adele</dd><dt>Age</dt><dd>16</dd><dt>Place</dt><dd>Pennsylvania</dd></li>
  <li><dt>Name</dt><dd href="#">Adele</dd><dt>Age</dt><dd>18</dd><dt>Place</dt><dd>New York</dd></li>
</ul>
```

The result of the `|` bit-wise operator will have the negative bit set when at least one of the `indexOf` is negative (-1). In that case the corresponding `li` should be hidden.

#### ES5 version

If your browser does not support ES6 (Internet Explorer), then use this ES5 compatible code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var i, dd,
      name = document.getElementById("myName").value.toUpperCase(),
      age = document.getElementById("myAge").value.toUpperCase(),
      place = document.getElementById("myPlace").value.toUpperCase(),
      ul = document.getElementById("myUL"),
      li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    dd = Array.prototype.map.call(li[i].getElementsByTagName("dd"), 
            function (dd) { return dd.textContent.toUpperCase() });
    li[i].style.display = 
        (dd[0].indexOf(name) | dd[1].indexOf(age) | dd[2].indexOf(place)) >= 0
            ? "" : "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myName" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
<input type="text" id="myAge" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for ages.." title="Type in a name">
<input type="text" id="myPlace" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for place.." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><dt>Name</dt><dd href="#">Adele</dd><dt>Age</dt><dd>16</dd><dt>Place</dt><dd>New York</dd></li>
  <li><dt>Name</dt><dd href="#">Mary</dd><dt>Age</dt><dd>17</dd><dt>Place</dt><dd>New Jersey</dd></li>
  <li><dt>Name</dt><dd href="#">Belle</dd><dt>Age</dt><dd>19</dd><dt>Place</dt><dd>New Mexico</dd></li>
  <li><dt>Name</dt><dd href="#">Adele</dd><dt>Age</dt><dd>16</dd><dt>Place</dt><dd>Pennsylvania</dd></li>
  <li><dt>Name</dt><dd href="#">Adele</dd><dt>Age</dt><dd>18</dd><dt>Place</dt><dd>New York</dd></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I have this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined(…)"

Comment: As you can see, this does not happen in the snippet I posted, so you will have something different. Which browser and version are you using?

Comment: And then I have thisUncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined(…)

Comment: I am using Chrome

Comment: Your code is different then. Without seeing it I cannot really assist

Comment: I just copy exactly the same thing into my code to test. This line dd => dd.textContent.toUpperCase()); has red underneath.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't work with screenshots. Please post your complete page on something like jsfiddle.

Comment: Why did you put a space between `=` and `>`. I did not post it like that, and it is a syntax error. It must be `=>`: it is the arrow function notation.

Comment: The fiddle is badly configured because it runs the code upon load, which means the function is not in the global scope. Also, you have left out the `id` of the `ul`, which you had in the question! See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g46es3b0/1/)

Comment: How did you fix the myFunction is not defined?

Comment: I reconfigured the fiddle -- click the icon in the JavaScript panel, and choose the way the script should be loaded. You had it on "onload", which is not good when you define functions. It is a bit misleading default setting in jsfiddle.

Comment: I keep getting Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined(…). And when I try to find where it caused the problem, the problem is right on the line : dd => dd.textContent.toUpperCase(); I have a red underline right under the "=>" said "expression expected". Do you have any other way to replace that statement?

Comment: `Array.from` and `=>` are ES6 features. It seems like you are running this in a browser that does not support ES6. I added an ES5 version to my answer.

Comment: It seems fixed the problem. Thank you. What is ES5 / E6? I am using webstorm of Inteliji and it automatically gives me the syntax problem. Thank you anyway

Comment: [ES5/ES6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269150/what-is-ecmascript) are EcmaScript language specifications, which browsers implement. ES6 was a major extension to the language, and published mid-2015. Many browsers already had some support for it back then, but Internet Explorer is lagging behind. See also: https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/05/ecmascript-6-in-webstorm-transpiling/