# What is relation between ES6 and Angular and Jquery. and Vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ecmascript-6

Was looking for some tutorial for ES6 and Vue.js but unable to find relation between them. want to know that ES6 can be implemented directly or it needs to be implemented by some script library like Jquery, Angular, or Vue.js. 
if it needs some script then how we tell the system to use ES6. 
or both are different.
I am trying to use this in MVC with C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read this to understand [ECMAScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33748435/5330546)

Angular, Vue, Jquery, React all are just  javaScript frameworks to ease things up.

so es6 can integrated with them together.

not all browsers have added the ECMAScript new features to their js engine, so were using tools like babel who's transpiling the es6 to es5 standarts.

and we use to wrap babel with webpack environment.