# Javascript generator function does not seem to be called

Tags: javascript, jestjs, generator

I have written the following Javascript function. It is supposed to return all the unique permutations (including partial permutations) of the elements of the input array; it is coded as a generator (introduced by `function*` and returning values using `yield`), so that the values are evaluated lazily on demand.

```js
function* permute(arr) {
    if (arr.length == 1)
        yield arr
    else if (arr.length) {
        for (let i of arr) {
            const value = arr[i]
            if (arr.indexOf(value) == i) {
                yield [value]
                const others = arr.slice(0, i).concat(arr.slice(i+1))
                for (let perm of permute(others))
                    yield [value, ...perm]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To test it, I used the following Jest unit test:

```js
describe("Permute tests", () => {
    test("No duplicates", () => {
        const input = "abc".split("")
        const expected = "a ab abc ac acb b ba bac bc bca c ca cab cb cba"
            .split(" ")
        for (let x of permute(input))
            expect(x.join("")).toBe(expected.shift())
        expect(expected.length).toBe(0)
    })
})
```

But when I run this, it doesn't give the expected results. The test fails at the last line because `expected.length` is not zero, it is 15 as no results from the generator have been processed. And this is borne out by the fact that if I put a breakpoint on the first statement in the generator function, it is not hit; it seems that next() is never called on the generator.

I have written other generators, and successfully tested them, but this one consistently doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Environment: NodeJS 14.16.0 and npm 7.10.0 on Windows 10 (or Ubuntu 20.04); Jest 26.6.3.

Comment: for (let i of arr) is iterating the array elements - not its indexes. But then you index arr on i.

Comment: Thank you, yes that is correct. I realised that, and once I changed it it does produce output. Not exactly the output I am expecting, but it is better than before.

Comment: I've just realised that the reason why it was not producing the output I expected is that `for (let i in arr)` does not iterate over the array indices as I reasonably expected; it iterates over the array indices **converted to strings**. 

Therefore, when (for example) processing the second element of a three-element array, the line `const others = arr.slice(0, i).concat(arr.slice(i+1))` doesn't create an array containing elements 0 and 2 as I expected; it creates one containing elements 0 and 11 - and 11 doesn't exist, so that slice is empty and the array only contains element 0.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to have some issue. it doesn't call recursively. you can check this link    [Recursive Generators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789593/recursive-generators-in-javascript)

I tried below one it produces with same logic unique characters

```
function* permute(arr) {
    if (arr.length == 1)
        yield arr
    else if (arr.length) {      
        for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {          
            const value = arr[i]            
            if (arr.indexOf(value) == i) {              
                //yield [value]                
                const others = arr.slice(0, i).concat(arr.slice(i+1))                     
                for (let perm of permute(others))                   
                    yield [value, ...perm]
            }
        }
    }
}
const p = permute("abc".split(""));
console.log(p.next().value)
```

Comment: It *does* call recursively (`for (let perm of permute(others)`).. But as @IamDranged pointed out, I was iterating over the array using a for...of loop when I should have used for...in. Your alternative code worked because you used a more conventional for loop.
Thanks anyway for taking the time to consider my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to those who have contributed answers; my code is now working. There were two problems, both relating to the way I was iterating over the array.

- The first problem was that I was saying `for (let i of arr)`, which iterates over the values, not the indices; and I was then trying to use `i` to index into `arr`.
- The second problem was that I changed it to `for (let i in arr)`, which iterates over the indices, **but treats them as strings, not numbers**. Therefore, in the line `const others = arr.slice(0, i).concat(arr.slice(i+1))`, the expression `i+1` didn't return a number that is one more than `i`, but a number that is the result of concatenating `i` and 1: that is, the equivalent of saying `i*10+1`. In order to overcome this, I can either use a conventional `for` loop instead of a `for...in` loop, or change the expression `i+1` to `i*1+1`. I think I prefer the former.

The amended version of the function, which works fine, is:

```js
function* permute(arr) {
    if (arr.length == 1)
        yield arr
    else if (arr.length) {
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            const value = arr[i]
            if (arr.indexOf(value) == i) {
                yield [value]
                const others = arr.slice(0, i).concat(arr.slice(i+1))
                for (const perm of permute(others))
                    yield [value, ...perm]
            }
        }
    }
}
```