# Relationship between Javascript, CoffeeScript, TypeScript, ES5 and ES6

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

What is the relationship between Javascript, CoffeeScript, TypeScript, ES5 and ES6? What is the trend in future?

I'm very confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the relationship between: javascript, coffeescript, typescript, ES5, ES6

## JavaScript

The base programming language in all these. ES5 and ES6 are just different *versions* of this language

## CoffeeScript

A language that compile down to JavaScript (hence called JS). Main focus is *terseness*.

## TypeScript

A language that compile down to JavaScript (hence called JS). Main focus is *type safety*.

> What is the trend in future

Its a complex system. Can't tell you the weather a year from now at a place.

## Recommendation

If you are just starting out in software dev, I still recommend TypeScript : https://medium.com/@basarat/should-i-learn-es5-es6-or-typescript-46c625c25d95

Comment: I think you can explain the relationship between JS and ES better. ECMAScript is a specification. JavaScript is an implementation of that standard. ES5/6 are different versions of the language specification.

Comment: @Halcyon: A simple link to [What is the difference between JavaScript and ECMAScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/912479/1048572) should suffice