# Is there a difference between the terms language-dialect and language-implementation?

Tags: javascript, terminology, ecma

For example: I've read JavaScript is a *dialect* of ECMAScript (the standard). I've also seen it mentioned as an *implementation* of ECMAScript. Is that largely a semantic difference? In other words can the terms *dialect* and *implementation* be used interchangeably.

EDIT: The question stems from the [ECMAScript Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) that mentions JavaScript along side V8 as both "Major Implementations" (right column of page), and a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912479/what-is-the-difference-between-javascript-and-ecmascript) that mentions JS as a dialect.

Comment: Dialect and implementation are entirely different things and are not interchangeable.

Comment: Note, wikipedia is not an official document published by the specification body referenced at Question.

Comment: Wikipedia simply inspired the question.

Comment: @Brandon See Brendan's Roadmap Updates: Popularity https://archive.is/siZ0m

Answer (score 2):

Yes. In general, dialect refers to what syntax is supported -- as with the `=>` fat arrow operator in JavaScript.

The implementation is what the underlying code is. In JavaScript, one popular implementation is the Google V8 engine.

But you can have two implementations that support the same dialect, and you can have versions of a single implementation that support different dialects.

Comment: "*Yes*"? "Dialect" infers a different grammar (among other things), so TypeScript might be an ECMAScript dialect, but JavaScript must adhere to ECMAScript grammar.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think my questions stems from the ECMAScript wikipedia page, that mentions JavaScript as "Major Implementation" of ECMAScript along side V8 (an engine). So while Javascript, to me, makes sense as a _dialect_, how is it also an implementation, along side v8?

Comment: @Brandon Can you include text and link to document that you are referencing at text of Question?

Comment: I've updated my question with respective references and clarification.

Answer (score 0):

When parsing the construction of words the rules govern the plain meaning of the words, as the goal is for clarity. If there is ambiguity, first consult dictionaries. If there is still controversy as to what the words mean, the next step is to find what the terms meant when the terms were first used and defined - as to that specific document and context.

Thus, the inquiry must by necessity go to step one, then two then three. Here, we must find the definitions of the terms as defined by the official bodies whom composed the terms. Research and find the actual earthling author or authors, if necessary, and ask them "what does this word mean"?

That path of determining what words or terms mean can be exhausting. Though, there are, most of the time, founding definitions which can be found. This does not mean that you will find what you are seeking, but rather, you will find the truth.

Some languages cannot be written or read as letters, incapable of being correctly understood without the keys to the symbols. On other occasions, your question as to specifics can be ignored, instead the response is to a different matter altogether. It is not a simple task to determine when a term was first used, and what it meant at the time it was first used in a specific context. Or, you may get no response at all.

Fortunately, the JavaScript language is well documented, relatively recently developed and active.

To find your Answer, ask the authors of the code itself. If you want to know   the clear and unambiguous definitions of terms within and specification or document, write to the author of the publication itself and ask the author of the publication for the precise meaning of the word or term.

Comment: You could have saved yourself a lot of typing by simply voting to close as *primarily opinion-based*. ;-)

Comment: @RobG The Question is not opinion based. Nor is the Answer. There are codified rules when the inquiry is to the construction of words or terms. Whether that be statutory construction or the "prior art" in the field of intellectual property. The inquiry begins with the "plain meaning" of the word or term. If there is controversy as to the meaning, dictionaries, technical documents, are consulted for clear, unambiguous definition. If that fails to produce and unambiguous definition the inquiry proceeds to what the terms meant when and where they were first used. We can ask the authors themselves

Comment: @RobG OP may not be aware of the science of the construction of words. While at first glance there might appear to be "opnion" involved, there is no opinion involved when you follow the rules for determining what words mean. It is incumbent upon OP to do their due diligence to contact the authors of the documents themselves to get the definitions they intended. All other routes of inquiry  would be opinion based. There is a difference between asking the author of code a question as to what a line means and asking a specification body what a term means. The latter requires technical specificity

Comment: The accepted answer to the OP's ["*here*" link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912479/what-is-the-difference-between-javascript-and-ecmascript) clearly points out that JavaScript is a dialect, not an implementation, of ECMAScript. So the OP is starting from a false premise which should have been apparent from their own reference.

Comment: @RobG The link at OP and linked Question are to wikipedia which cannot be cited as source of official documentation; any individual can edit wikipedia. Do not gather a premise presented by OP; rather an inquiry, albeit not to the organization which publishes their official documentation, but to SO at large; seeking clarification as to two technical terms that could be defined outside of the scope of a common meaning. Therefor, the author or authors of the specific official document or their governing body, should be asked directly what the unambiguous definitions of the terms, as applied, are.

Comment: @RobG Generally, official technical documentation has some form of preface termed "Definitions", where the terms used therein are defined as to that document version. Not sure if OP has researched the official document or documents which they appear to be referencing to locate the "Definitions" section. That is part duty of OP. Have not done the search for OP, here. Lacking a "Definitions" section within one or more of the official documents of the specification body, OP can pose a formal Question to the specification body itself. And, or ask the specific Question at https://esdiscuss.org/.